# How to move out variables declaration from a bat file to another bat file?

Tags: postgresql, command-line, system-administration

I need to create 2 .bat files:

1. To dump my PostgreSQL database
2. To restore the PostgreSQL database

How can I move out variables (database name, login, passw, etc...) to an external file so both .bat files can use the same external file with variable declarations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File #1, e.g. setup_env.cmd

```
set server=localhost
set db=postgres
set port=5432
```

File #2, e.g. do_dump.cmd

```
call ~dp0setup_env.cmd
pg_dump -h %server% -p %port% %db%
```

Answer (score 1):

with defaults:

```
set server=localhost
set db=yourdb
set port=5432

if {%1}=={} goto dostuff
set server=%1

if {%2}=={} goto dostuff
set db=%2

if {%3}=={} goto dostuff
set port=%3


:dostuff

ECHO


<your command> %server% %db% %port%
```

You can call it from different file:

```
call dump.bat <servername> <dbname> <portnumber>
```